# Rationale behind Q-learning

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am reading Sutton Barto on Reinforcement Learning. I understand that $TD(\lambda)$ methods propose better performance than Monte Carlo methods, with TD methods combining advantages of Dynamic Programming and Monte Carlo approaches.

The transition to Q-methods : SARSA, Q-Learning, Expected SARSA is unclear to me. Which gaps is filled by Q-methods, what is the rational behind their use rather than TD methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The transition to Q-methods : SARSA, Q-Learning, Expected SARSA is unclear to me. Which gaps is filled by Q-methods, what is the rational behind their use rather than TD methods ?

There isn't really such a thing as "Q methods" in the sense that you are using it. All of SARSA, Q-learning and Expected SARSA are TD methods. Specifically they are using TD approach in the context of *action values*, which is necessary for value based model-free control problems, because if you just used state values $V(s)$ then you have no way to generate your best guess at the optimal policy. Using $Q(s,a)$ immediately gives you $\pi(s) = \text{max}_a Q(s,a)$.

Model-free Monte Carlo control likewise must use estimates of $Q(s,a)$ which is why there is not really a clear class of methods called "Q methods", although it is a matter of convention what all these things are called and they are all inter-related in any case.